# mongoQB for Codeigniter Implementation

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter

Since I am already implementing the old version of [mongodb from alexbilbie](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library), but the current mongoDB driver newer than 1.3 for php is not compatible anymore except I am migrating to alexbilbie’s new library called [mongoQB](https://github.com/alexbilbie/MongoQB), anyone has experience with that or could give a sample procedure to integrate this mongoQB to codeigniter? I am scratching my head currently…

I know I could also use a native implementation of mongoDB to php but I have already made many models based on alexbilbie’s old version and it would be better for me to change syntax names than to rewriting all the models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked mongoqb and modified it a bit to integrate it with codeigniter. You can find the library here [mongoci](https://github.com/sp3tsnaz/mongoci)

Comment: wow, thank you for responding to my question. Have not tried it but it looks good. I will fork it and try as soon as I have spare time. I marked your answer then.